# Помогите в ДЗ по выбору местоимения

Tags: грамотная-речь, местоимения

В каких случаях допустимо употребление обоих притяжательных местоимений?

1. Аспирант попросил своего научного руководителя прочитать (свой, его) доклад.
2. Пушкин был сослан в (свое, его) имение.
3. Согласно (своему, его) завещанию он был похоронен на деревенском кладбище.
4. Он не приукрашивает (своей, его) жизни.
5. Я был тогда вдали от (своих, его) друзей.

Или дайте, пожалуйста, ссылку на нормальную статью по теме. Я так и не смог найти полезную информацию про использование этих местоимений.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что ДЗ.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Comment: @Aer Так как я сам добавил ответ на свой вопрос, то мне придется подождать 5 часов, чтобы сделать это.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*1. Аспирант попросил своего научного руководителя прочитать (**свой, его**) доклад.*

Согласно Розенталю местоимение «свой» относится ко всем 3-м лицам, поэтому при наличии в предложении нескольких существительных или местоимений, с которыми потенциально может соотноситься возвратное местоимение, нередко возникает неясность. В подобных случаях местоимение «свой» следует относить к слову, называющему производителя соответствующего действия.
Таким образом, слово свой следует отнести к научному руководителю как производителю действия, выраженного инфинитивом прочитать, с которым связано сочетание свой доклад. То есть научный руководитель прочитает свой доклад.
Как в примере Розенталя, так и здесь присутствует неясность, связанная с тем, к какому лицу относится данное местоимение.
А вдруг предполагалось, что будет прочитан доклад студента? В таком случае предложение должно быть преобразовано так, чтобы его можно было трактовать однозначно.
Местоимение «его» используется для указания на признак по принадлежности третьему лицу (ссылка 2). Здесь третьим лицом здесь является и научный руководитель, и студент. Опять возникает двусмысленность.
Таким образом, использовать здесь можно оба местоимения. Правда, может возникнуть неясность.

*2. Пушкин был сослан в (**свое**, его) имение.*

Местоимение «свой», как и возвратное, указывает на принадлежность предмета, качества, свойства лицу (активному производителю действия) и может относиться ко всем трём лицам и к обоим числам (Розенталь, ссылка 3). Если имение принадлежит Пушкину, то правильным будет вариант с местоимением «свой».

*3. Согласно (своему, **его**) завещанию он был похоронен на деревенском кладбище.*

Местоимение «свой», как и возвратное, указывает на принадлежность предмета, качества, свойства лицу (активному производителю действия) и может относиться ко всем трём лицам и к обоим числам (Розенталь, ссылка 3). Так как **"он"** не может быть активным производителем действия, то и местоимение «свой» мы использовать не можем.

*4. Он не приукрашивает (**своей, его**) жизни.*

В данном случае мы можем использовать местоимение «свой», так как имеется активный производитель действия.
Местоимение «его» используется для указания на признак по принадлежности третьему лицу (ссылка 2). Мы можем использовать местоимение «его», в таком случае он будет не приукрашивать не свою жизнь, а жизнь какого-то другого человека.

*5. Я был тогда вдали от (**своих, его**) друзей.*

Аналогично предыдущему предложению.

Я не уверен до конца в правильности моих рассуждений, но так как задание засчитали, то, по крайней мере, были выбраны правильные местоимения. Благодарю всех за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

**У Розенталя есть информация на эту тему, но и она не дает четкого ответа в неясных случаях.**

Поэтому **рекомендация для автора такова:** структура предложения должна   обеспечивать однозначность понимания смысла при использовании притяжательных местоимений.

[§170. Возвратные и притяжательные местоимения](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/60.htm#%D0%B7_02)

Comment: Благодарю за помощь. Эта книга очень помогла. Если тема вам интересна, то посмотрите на результат, к которому я пришел.

Answer (score -1):

Аспирант попросил своего научного руководителя прочитать свой доклад.
Пушкин был сослан в свое имение.
Согласно его завещанию он был похоронен на деревенском кладбище.
Он не приукрашивает своей жизни.
Я был тогда вдали от своих друзей.

Притяжательное местоимение свой указывает на признак по принадлежности предмета любому главному действующему лицу: Я показал свои фотографии, и он показал свои фотографии. Покажи и ты свои фотографии.

Comment: Спасибо. Я сделал абсолютно также. Однако преподаватель сказала мне, что предложения 1, 4, 5 неправильны. Учитывая наличие в задании вопроса "В каких случаях допустимо употребление обоих притяжательных местоимений?", может быть, допустимо использовать оба местоимения в этих предложениях (1, 4 и 5)?

Comment: *Я сделал абсолютно также.* "Так же" в этом случае пишут раздельно.

Comment: На сайте не выполняют ДЗ.

Comment: Артём, вы абсолютно правы. "Так же" пишут раздельно в этом случае. Вот только это мне никак не помогло.

Comment: shampar, серьёзно? Обычное ДЗ? Тогда почему я нигде не нашел нормального объяснения, показывающего, какое из этих местоимений следует использовать? Тот же Розенталь (см. выше) лишь коротко затрагивает эту тему.

Comment: Мне кажется, что оба местоимения могут быть в тех случаях, когда у фраз может быть разный смысл. На мой взгляд, это как раз 1, 4 и 5. И в третьем я бы сказал "своему завещанию", но могу и ошибаться. 1. свой = руководителя, его = аспиранта. 4. своей — ясно, его — своего героя, например. 5. его — в принципе, можно быть далеко и от друзей своего знакомого или тоже друга, например (насколько пример реален, судите сами). Во втором Пушкина тоже, конечно, могли сослать в чужое имение, но мне это кажется ещё менее вероятным. В третьем вариантов нету, вопрос только, как правильно.

Comment: @СергейКривошеин Я тут пытаюсь Вам помочь, а Вы молчите всё. Могли бы поблагодарить хоть за старания, даже если ничего полезного не нашли в моих мыслях или считаете их неправильными. Возразить можно что-то. А то можно подумать, что помощь мне нужна была!

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Извините, к тому времени я уже лег спать. Благодарю за оказанную помощь. Это задание я выполнил вчера ночью, до того как вы отправили ваше сообщение, но я не был уверен в его правильности, поэтому и не стал ничего писать о его выполнении. Преподаватель сегодня проверила моё решение, и оно оказалось верным. Так что я сейчас его добавлю в качестве ответа.